# Ansible: Convert two lists into key, value dict

Tags: ansible

I have 2 lists as set_fact and want to create a dict

I am running ansible 2.8
I have list1 as below

```
  "inventory_devices": [
        "device0", 
        "device1" 
    ]
```

and list2 as below

```
"inventory_ips": [
    "10.1.1.1", 
    "10.1.1.2" 
]
```

I want to get an output shows like

```
"inventory_dict": [
    "device0": "10.1.1.1",
    "device1": "10.1.1.2"
]
```

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try already to get to your result ?

Comment: provided bottom of this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the task to do it, `populate combined var` in the PB below:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    inventory_devices:
      - device0
      - device1
    inventory_ips:
      - 10.1.1.1
      - 10.1.1.2

  tasks:
    - name: populate combined var
      set_fact:
        combined_var: "{{ combined_var|default({}) | combine({ item.0: item.1 }) }}"
      loop: "{{ query('together', inventory_devices, inventory_ips) }}"

    - name: print combined var
      debug:
        var: combined_var
```

result:

```
TASK [print combined var] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "combined_var": {
        "device0": "10.1.1.1",
        "device1": "10.1.1.2"
    }
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: I tried the below.
tasks
   - name: create inventory_list
     set_fact: 
         inventory_list: "{{ inventory_var|default({}) | combine ( {{ item.0 }} : {{ item.1 }}) }}"
     with_together:
         - inventory_devices
         - inventory_ips

I found my mistake. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it entirely with jinja2 using the [`zip` filter built into ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#zip-filter).

> To get a list combining the elements of other lists use zip
>
> ```
> - name: give me list combo of two lists
>   debug:
>     msg: "{{ [1,2,3,4,5] | zip(['a','b','c','d','e','f']) | list }}"
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Similarly to the output of the items2dict filter mentioned above, these filters can be
>   used to contruct a `dict`:
>
> ```
> {{ dict(keys_list | zip(values_list)) }}
> ```

The `zip` filter sequentially combines items from pairs of lists and the `dict` construct creates a dictionary from a list of pairs.

```
inventory_dict: "{{ dict(inventory_devices | zip(inventory_ips)) }}"
```

Comment: This is single command which is awesome, but i don't know what zip command does?

Comment: It takes two lists and combines items from them, one from each, into pairs, which make a new list: A list of lists.